# sed to remove url in-place from file

Tags: sed

I am trying to remove in-place a specific url from a file using `sed` and currently the command below runs but the url is still in the file.  Thank you :)

**list**

```
xxxx://www.xxx.com/xxx/xx/xxx/file.html
xxxx://www.xxx.com/xxx/xx/xxx/file1.bam
xxxx://www.xxx.com/xxx/xx/xxx/file2.bam
xxxx://www.xxx.com/xxx/xx/xxx/file1.vcf.gz
xxxx://www.xxx.com/xxx/xx/xxx/file2.vcf.gz
```

**desired output**

```
file.html
file1.bam
file2.bam
file1.vcf.gz
file2.vcf.gz
```

**sed command**

```
sed -i -e 's|xxxx://www.xxx.com/xxx/xx/xxx/.*/||' /home/cmccabe/list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an extra directory listed in your sed script. Watch how things line up:

```
             xxxx://www.xxx.com/xxx/xx/xxx/file.html
                                           ↓
sed -i -e 's|xxxx://www.xxx.com/xxx/xx/xxx/.*/||' /home/cmccabe/list
```

Your substitution appears to require that the file exist in a directory under `xxxx://www.xxx.com/xxx/xx/xxx/` rather than within that directory itself. Remove the extra directory requirement, or make it optional, and your sed substitution works as-is.

What you're looking for is likely either:

```
sed -i -e 's|xxxx://www\.xxx\.com/xxx/xx/xxx/||'  /home/cmccabe/list
```

or

```
sed -i -r -e 's|xxxx://www\.xxx\.com/xxx/xx/xxx/(.+/)?||'  /home/cmccabe/list
```

or to permit only one level of subdirectories:

```
sed -i -r -e 's|xxxx://www\.xxx\.com/xxx/xx/xxx/([^/]+/)?||'  /home/cmccabe/list
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
sed 's|.*/||' /home/cmccabe/list
```

`.*/` will match greedy from the start of the string until the last occurrence of `/` and replaces that by nothing.

Btw, with the help of `xargs` you can also use the `basename` command:

```
xargs -a /home/cmccabe/list -n1 basename
```

Comment: Um, no, I'm pretty sure the question says that the OP wants a *specific* URL removed, rather than all URLs stripped. The problem he's having is identified in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35365970/1072112).

Comment: Thank you for your help it is working now with the specified url being removed from the file :)